# How to fetch data with pivot table using where condition on pivot in laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, pivot

How can I fetch data with belongsToMany relation models.

```
Table tags
  - id
  - name
  ...

Table photo_entries
  - id
  ...

Table photo_entry_tag
  - id
  - tag_id
  - photo_entry_id
```

**Tag.php**

```
public function photo_entry()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PhotoEntry');
}
```

**PhotoEntry.php**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Now I need to fetch `photo entries` from `photo_entries` table with their tags `where tag_id=1`.

**I have tried this:**

```
$photos = PhotoEntry::orderBy('votes', 'desc')->with(array('tags' => function($query)
{
   $query->where('tag_id', 1); 
}))->paginate(50);
```

But its not giving me the proper result, its returning all photos. I am not getting what is the issue.

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all records form **photo_entries** table that has a relation in **photo_entry_tag** table so to do that your query should be like this

```
$tag_id = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo_entries` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `photo_entry_id` FROM `photo_entry_tag` WHERE `tag_id` = {$tag_id})";
```

Also the equivalence code in eloquent will be like the code below

```
$tag_id = 1;
$photos = PhotoEntry::whereIn('id', function($query) use ($tag_id) {
    $query->select('photo_entry_id')->from('photo_entry_tag')->whereTagId($tag_id
);
})->get();
```

Also you can add `orderBy('votes', 'desc')` just before `get()` to sort the result